# Find occurrences of certain matrix inside a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory

This problem occurred from my need to find all graphs with a certain topology inside a bigger one. I don't need the subgraphs but the graphs that have the exact topology I am searching.

We know for a fact that we can represent graph networks with a Laplacian matrix. If I wanted to check the entire graph it would take $n^2 \times n$ for the diagonal and $2^n$ for checking the row and column of each element.

Is there a better way to do this? Either by using matrices or graph theory?

For example below i want to find all the upper left matrices inside a big matrix and also check that the rest of their columns and rows are zero.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-1 & 3 & -2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 3 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & n \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Your description is inadequate. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay added an example

Comment: So given graphs $G$ and $H$, you're looking to see if you can find all subgraphs of $G$ which are isomorphic to $H$?  Finding one is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) I'm afraid.

Comment: I tried to turn your picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvGUD.png into TeX, which we usually encourage for searchability.  However, I couldn't figure out what was supposed to be happening at the bottom of the picture.  Please feel free to edit further if I got it wrong.